# UITextView Right Alignment [incorrect behaviour]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

[image]I set my TextView's Alignment to right using this code line but the appeared text sometimes in right, sometimes in left. I don't know why, I searched more about this problem . I was set text before using

```
[self.textView sizeToFit];
[self.textView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
```

[image]

Thanks a lot
Nada

Comment: Can you put some more code, and show the exact problem where in image?

Comment: Where you write this code?

Comment: Are you trying to place image and text together in the textview? If yes, you need to use   + (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringWithAttachment:(NSTextAttachment *)attachment. If yes, let me know, i can show the usage in my answer.

Comment: Viral , I added new image explained the textView . I pass text from service to textView .

Comment: Avi , No it's a plain text only .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you use:

```
[self.textView sizeToFit];
```

your UITextView will be exactly the size of the text.
Alignment won't matter anymore, since it's only use to control alignment inside the box (it doesn't work like float: right in HTML as people might expect).

It looks like that:

[image]

If you set a background color for your UITextView - you will understand it better within your own application.

One of solutions is to keep your UITextView to be full width of screen, don't do `sizeToFit` and set right aligment - than box remains full width and alignment will work.

If you need to move UITextViews around, you should use dynamic constrains to control that - but I would suggest to do it as above to make is simpler.

Comment: Grzegorz , Thanks a lot for your answer you are right about sizeToFit , I tested to set backgroundColor , and I found what you are saying . But when i remove sizeToFit the content still in left .